# what is the probability of two randomly generated 4 digit numbers being the same

Tags: probability

The probability of one four digit number is $\frac1{9000}$. The probability of any second four digit number is also $\frac1{9000}$ as the trials are independent. But what is the probability of two four digit numnbers being the same. Is it still $\frac1{9000}$ or is it $\frac1{9000}\cdot \frac1{9000}$?

Been $55$ years since my statistics course.

Answer (score 1):

It's just $\frac1{9000}$.

The first number can be any feasible number $9000$ choices, the second number must be the first number.  Hence $\frac{9000}{9000^2}=\frac1{9000}$

Or:

Let the two random number be $A$ and $B$.

$$Pr(A=B)=\sum_bPr(A=B|B=b)Pr(B=b)=\sum_bPr(A=b)Pr(B=b)=\frac1{9000}$$

Note that $\frac1{9000^2}$ is the probability of obtaining the same fixed number for both random number.